# WebSocket with Spring backend loses connection after a while, onclose is not called

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket, basic-authentication, spring-websocket

In our spring application most of the controllers are protected with oauth security. Websockets are behind basic. Before accessing websocket logged user asks for username and hashed password for websocket connection. Both are going to be generated, but for now for testing purposes it always returns the same creditentials.

URL for info looks as follows:

```
 https://user:debaee4affbeaba909a184066981d55a@localhost:8000/project-name/chat/info
```

WebSocket is opened properly. We can send few messages and they go trough broker and are displayed to the users. Here's request info from chrome tools:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:https://benny:debaee4affbeaba909a184066981d55a@localhost:8000/project-name/chat/033/7szz8k_f/xhr_send
Request Method:POST
Status Code:204 No Content

Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: DENY
access-control-allow-origin: https://localhost:8000
access-control-allow-credentials: true
vary: Origin
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 08:22:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Request Headers:
POST /project-name/chat/033/7szz8k_f/xhr_send HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 143
Origin: https://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: https://localhost:8000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=FF967D3DD1247C1D572C15CF8A3D5E8E; i18next=en; language=pl; tmhDynamicLocale.locale=%22pl-pl%22

["SEND\npriority:9\ndestination:/random/chat/1/FUNNY\ncontent-length:49\n\n{\"message\":\"sfsdf\",\"display\":\"The great wizard.\"}\u0000"]
```

But after a minute or so when sending another request we get 404 response. It doesn't matter if any SEND requests were issued before. We can write 50+ messages in that time span and then we get 404.

Sample 404 request data follows:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:https://hill:debaee4affbeaba909a184066981d55a@localhost:8000/project-name/chat/033/7szz8k_f/xhr_send
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found

Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: DENY
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 08:24:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Request Headers:
POST /project-name/chat/033/7szz8k_f/xhr_send HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 143
Origin: https://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: https://localhost:8000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=FF967D3DD1247C1D572C15CF8A3D5E8E; i18next=en; language=pl; tmhDynamicLocale.locale=%22pl-pl%22

Request Payload:
["SEND\npriority:9\ndestination:/random/chat/1/FUNNY\ncontent-length:49\n\n{\"message\":\"yhgfh\",\"username\":\"The great wizard.\"}\u0000"]
```

When setting up stomp we setup function to react onclose:

```
socket.client = new SockJS(targetUrl);
socket.stomp = Stomp.over(socket.client);
socket.stomp.connect({}, startListener);
socket.stomp.onclose = reconnect;
```

With reconnect function looking as this(it's in AngularJS):

```
var reconnect = function() {
                    $log.debug('Reconnect called');
                    $timeout(function() {
                        initialize();
                    }, this.RECONNECT_TIMEOUT);
};
```

But the function is never called.

Controller for Chat is pretty simple:

```
@Controller
public class StageChatController {

    @Inject
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Inject
    private ChatMessageRepository chatMessageRepository;

@MessageMapping("/chat/{channel}/{type}")
    public void sendMessage(@DestinationVariable Long channel, @DestinationVariable ChatType type, ChatMessageDto message) {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();

        chatMessage.setDatestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        chatMessage.setMessage(message.getMessage());
        chatMessage.setChannelId(channel);
        chatMessage.setChatType(type);
        chatMessage.setDisplayName(message.getDisplay());

        chatMessage = this.chatMessageRepository.save(chatMessage);

        this.template.convertAndSend("/channel/" + project + "/" + type, chatMessage);
    }
```

Security for chat overrides oauth security for chat urls:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(2)
    static class BasicAccessConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Inject
        private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter;

        @Value("${project.name.chat.token}")
        private String chat_token;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //@formatter:off
            http
            .requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/chat/**/*"))
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(this.oauth2ClientContextFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
            ;
            //@formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("hill").password(this.chat_token).authorities("read_chat");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's something wrong with how security is handled. When I disabled security completely on backend side the websocket never gets 404.

Comment: We've setup this on another server and it works alright even with security. No matter what we do it still stops after 1 minute on first server and on our development platforms if the security is enabled. Everywhere we use the same version of Java, Tomcat8. Both test servers are on debian(exactly the same version), while our development machines vary from windows to various versions of linux.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same symptoms in our app

Comment: did someone found solution for this?

Comment: We haven't found the solution yet